# Dropdown list depends on other Dropdown list in IE and doesn't update vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I'm using VBA to automate IE. I have two dropdown lists (let's call them "A" and "B"). The B list depends on the values of the A list, so the B list won't show its values unless I select the A list value manually first. I tried with this:

```
 Sub pifa ()

      Dim ie As Object
      
      Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
      
      With ie
          .Visible = True
          .navigate "https://serviciosjava2.pifa.gob/rcel/jsp/index_bis.jsp"

           Do While .Busy
               DoEvents
           Loop

           Do While .readyState <> 4
                DoEvents
           Loop
           
                ie.document.getElementById("puntodeventa").Value = "31" 'A list value

           Do While .Busy
               DoEvents
           Loop

           Do While .readyState <> 4
                DoEvents
           Loop
           
                ie.document.getElementById("universocomprobante").Value = "19" 'B list value (doesn't work)
      
      End with

 End sub
```

For the A list value everything is OK, it changes the dropdown list value correctly, but as I didn't actually clicked manually the value, the B list won't update and show the values. I also tried this, and doesn't work:

```
 ie.document.getElementById("puntodeventa").Click 'A list value
```

"A" list code:

```
<select name="puntoDeVenta" onchange="actualizarDescripcionPVConDelay(this.selectedIndex);ajaxFunction();" id="puntodeventa">
        <option value="" selected="selected" style="color:#888;" onclick=document.getElementById("desc_pto_vta").innerHTML="";>seleccionar...</option>
                        
        <option value="31">&nbsp;puntodeventaseleccionado</option>
                        
</select>
```

"B" list code:

```
 <select name="universoComprobante" onchange="actualizarDescripcionTC(this.selectedIndex);" id="universocomprobante">
        <option value="" selected="selected" style="color:#888;">seleccionar...</option>
                        
        <option value="10">Factura A</option> 'this appears when I click manually the A list

        <option value="19">Factura B</option> 'this appears when I click manually the A list

                        
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding this below the value entrance:

```
 ie.document.getElementById("puntodeventa").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the HTML code then you can notice that both dropdown control has **onchange** event.

After setting the value you need to fire the onchange event from your VBA code may help to fix the issue.

Sample code to fire onchange event.

```
Set ieEvent = htmldoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
ieEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
ie.document.all.Item("puntoDeVenta").dispatchEvent ieEvent
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it made me investigate about the onchange event. I couldn't  solve it with your code because html references are not working for me.